# Web Sockets Installation in Windows

Tags: php, mysql, web, websocket, real-time-updates

I am confused about using nodejs. I need help in it. All I want to do is to create a PHP MySql Application that shows sales information of any office. I want the data to be in real time. That is whenever a change is made to the database the result is displayed into the web page without page refresh. After doing a research, I found that nodejs and socketio can do this work, but I'm not sure how to implement this. I'm using a XAMPP localhost in office. I really need a help on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: I don't understand what node.JS has to do with building a PHP/mySQL application?

Comment: I want it in real time. There are 50 computers connected and each person has  an account. So when one person makes any change the other people knows like facebook notifications.

Comment: Dainis Abols - I did'nt get your question.

Comment: @SubrataBanerjee Yes this can be implemented nicely in Node because you can avoid the database poll with its event-driven nature, but if your Javascript skills are not up to scratch this is a complete non-starter. This question as it stands will be closed because it is way too vague, you need to have a go at it yourself and come back with more specific questions related to *your* code, rather than asking where to start with it. I would just start by getting websockets working with Ajax calls just passing some arbitrary data between clients, and leave the database layer until later.

Comment: @DaveRandom All I want to know is how this implementation can be done. I also came across Push Technology and getting confused. Need Help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider the following approach: from within your PHP, do a push of data via an outgoing HTTP/POST to a WebSocket server. The WebSocket server maintains the real-time connections to your JavaScript frontends. Upon receiving data, the JS updates the UI. When your PHP app is a classic one (not a single-page web app), that means new page loads when the user navigates through your Web app. Which in turn means loosing the WS connection and reestablishing it.

These are some challenges:

- You need not only a WebSocket server, but on top of that some message brokering (publish & subscribe).
- That server needs to have a HTTP/POST (REST) endpoint for your PHP to push to.

If you want to go with a hosted cloud service, I'd recommend looking at pusher.com.

If you want to get going fast, host your own stuff, but don't want to build/develop the functionality, you may look at http://www.tavendo.de/webmq
Here is an example: https://github.com/tavendo/WebMQConnectPHP/tree/master/examples/basic

Disclosure: I work for Tavendo.

Comment: If it helped you, consider upvoting or even accepting the answer;)